# How to check if Field is null when two tables joins

Tags: c#, sql, database, ms-access

I have two tables in Ms-Access. I want to check if `RollNo` is `null` gives **-1** otherwise give the `RollNo`. I am querying tables with inner join in c# application.
This the query:

```
select isnull(s.RollNo, -1) as Roll, c.Class from students s inner join Classes c on s.ClassID = c.ClassID
```

when I run this query, it gives empty value in `Roll`.

Comment: Is RollNo `null` or simply empty? What type it is - number, char?

Comment: Simply Empty. Type is number

Answer (score 1):

The syntax is this, using *Nz*:

```
select Nz(s.RollNo, -1) as Roll, ...
```

Else, if outside Access:

```
select iif(s.RollNo is null, -1, s.RollNo) as Roll, ...
```

Comment: this work in Ms-Access. But i have to use this query in C# application. Outside Ms-Access `nz` not work.

Comment: @MuhammadRizwan . . . Your question is tagged MS Access, so this answers the question that you asked.  If you have a C# question, then as a new question and tag it appropriately.

Comment: I have tried the edited answer. But it gives still empty cell of `Roll`.

Comment: Perhaps you have empty strings, not Nulls, see edited answer, please. Double-check your data - we can't do that for you.

Comment: `RollNo` field type is number. @Gustav

Comment: Then you have either a value or Null. Check with `select s.RollNo as Roll, ...`

Comment: I have added field properties in Question @Gustav. I have tried this `select s.RollNo, ...` gives empty cell.

Comment: I have tried `nz` in ms-access. this isn't working. Giving empty value in ms-access @Gustav

Comment: Then something else is going on. A numeric field can only hold _Null_ or a number.

Comment: so what's the solution?? @Gustav

Comment: I don't know. What you report is "not possible", so something else is going on, or you data differs from what you think they are. Double-check everything and debug until you find the reason.